# sqoop `--direct` doesn't work with `--incremental lastmodified`?

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2

I was trying to test 2 tasks. `--incremental append` and `--incremental lastmodified`. Below is mySQL database schema.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id      INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ts      TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

The below code sqoop will work.

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test \
  --username fake \
  --password fake \
  --table test1 \
  --incremental append \
  --check-column id \
  --last-value 9 \
  --direct \
  --num-mappers 1
```

However, if I do `--incremental lastmodified` with `--direct`, it will not return any modified records. If I do it without `--direct`, it will work correctly.

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test \
  --username fake \
  --password fake \
  --table test1 \
  --incremental lastmodified \
  --merge-key id \
  --check-column ts \
  --direct \
  --last-value "some time here" \
  --num-mappers 1
```

Why is this? I know `--direct` doesn't support import of some data types, but I don't think this is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using JDBC driver for transferring data, the direct mode delegates the job of transferring data to the native utilities.

In case of MySQL `mysqldump` and `mysqlimport` are used. There are many performance benefits using this but it comes with many limitations.

During `--incremental lastmodified` or `--incremental append` a custom query is generated where record by record from the table are compared to find the set of records that are required to import.

To summarize `--direct` is like a bulk import where there is no lookup on individual field, but `--incremental lastmodified` or `--incremental append` requires individual fields for lookups to find the data required to gather and load into hdfs. This is why both `--direct` and `--incremental` cannot co-exists.

Comment: but why did it work for `append` but not `lastmodified`?